# Is there a GUI application to create Snaps?

Tags: snap

I have a Python application which I was able to turn into a .deb with the help of the simple but effective Debreate program to put on GetDeb. Is there an equivalent piece of software for creating a Snap? Alternatively, even a Bash or Python script would do. Would I have to put the code in a Git repository?

Comment: There hasn't been any mentions of one  , but capable developers are always welcome to step in and make one :)

Comment: Noooo! No thanks Serg. The only reason I wrote the Python application is that I wanted to use it - it was vastly more effort than I anticipated. It did of course occur to me to write the "simple Snap creation" application, but I resisted it :)

Comment: This is technically off topic, as it's a question about future Ubuntu releases. There is an answer though.

Comment: Maybe Alien will add support for snaps some day ... in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When the phone/tablet images start moving to using snaps, the *Ubuntu SDK* will be the primary GUI for creating snaps.